# ModelView, Ajax and Json return

Tags: ajax, spring, model-view-controller

In my code, i have two RequestMapper in my Controller which is designed this way :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/myHostel.html")
public class HostelController
{

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getText()
    {
        // do some cool stuff but not the point here
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getMyUrl()
    {
        String myVariable;
        return "{\"myUrl\": \""+myVariable+"\""}";
    }

}
```

And my ajax code :

```
function openNewTab() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'myHostel.html',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");  
        },
        success : function(response){           
            console.log(response);

            window.open(response.url, '_blank');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception, errorThrown)
        {
            console.log(jqXHR.status);
            console.log(exception);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

and my button is kinda like this :

```
<button tabindex="0" id="mySweetButton" class="btn btn-primary" 
    onclick="openNewTab();" >
    Open a new tab
</button>
```

And what i get is :
200
parsererror
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

--

I've tried with putting a session variable in the model and a   making a window.open(URL_IN_SESSION);

But if you reload the page, it's calling it again.

Making a c:remove on the variable when it's not used to cancel this problem but to no avail.

I have to get a variable from my ModelView after some previous call and open it in ajax (or javascript whatever as long as it works) to have my main page and my new tab with the custom URL.

If anyone has a idea on what i'm doing wrong ? (I need a custom URL made in my controller by previous GET call with user choices.)

Thank you for reading !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by making just another GET requestMapping using no parameters and with value = ("/myHostel.html/getMyUrl.html")

One of the problem was the filters that only allowed .html url for the mapping.

The other was the JSON, just using :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/getUrl.html")
public ResponseEntity<String> sendUrl()
{
    return new ResponseEntity<>(getMyUrl(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And parsing the return in ajax :

```
function openNewTab() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'myHostel.html/getUrl.html',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'text',
        success : function(data){
            window.open(data, '_blank');
        }
    });
}
```

And it solved the problem.